# Can't find Custom Database Table in Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I have created a custom module that creates a custom Database table. I have been following Alan Storm's tutorials http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources and http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm in order to create custom Database tables.

My module entry gets showed up in core_resource table but the actual doesn't get showed up.

This is my config.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <Ajzele_SimpleModel>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Ajzele_SimpleModel>
</modules>
<global>

  <models>
   <simplemodel>
     <class>Ajzele_SimpleModel_Model</class>
     <resourceModel>simplemodel_mysql4</resourceModel>      
   </simplemodel>

   <simplemodel_mysql4>
     <class>Ajzele_SimpleModel_Model_Mysql4</class>
      <entities>
          <simplemodel>
                  <table>simplemodel</table>
           </simplemodel>
       </entities>                
   </simplemodel_mysql4>  

 </models>

 <resources>
        <simplemodel_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Ajzele_SimpleModel</module>
       <class>Ajzele_SimpleModel_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>

            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>

        </simplemodel_setup>

        <simplemodel_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </simplemodel_read>  

        <simplemodel_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </simplemodel_write>  

</resources>        
</global>    
    </config>
```

And my Model file Structure is

```
   Model
     SimpleModel.php
     Mysql4
       SimpleModel.php
       Setup.php
       SimpleModel
          Collection.php
```

Here's teh contents of my sql/simplemodel_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
     <?php

    $installer = $this;

   $installer->startSetup();

   $baseTableName = 'simplemodel';

   $sql = "
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
   -- ----------------------------
   -- Table structure for `simplemodel`
   -- ----------------------------
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable($baseTableName)};
   CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable($baseTableName)} (
    `simplemodel_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `field2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`simplemodel_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ";

    $installer->run($sql);

    $installer->endSetup();
```

I have tried various debugging methods, but I get neither any exception nor an error. What should I do in order to get my table actually show up in Database?

Comment: There's not enough information here.  We'll at least need the contents of your `sql/` folder.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Remove the entry in `core_resource` table to have the install script run again.

Comment: if I delete the entry from core_resource table n reload the page I get the an error. The error report gives this as the first line "/home/atsdev/public_html/app/code///sql/simplemodel_setup not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you put Magento in developer mode and debug the trace of XML to check the XML. To configure Magento in developer Mode you should put the variable MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE in the definition of the virtual host or in the .htaccess of the Magento root. 
For example in de virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs/local.pruebas.com"
   ServerName local.pruebas.com
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
   SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "1"    
   <Directory "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs/local.pruebas.com">
       AllowOverride All
       Options All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

later you should modify index.php  in the line 66 and put

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Varien_Profiler::enable();
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 }
```

Varien_Profiler::enable(); and  ini_set('display_errors', 1); is out of conditional i think for mistake.
Now, you can´t see the simplexml_load_string() error whent have an error in the XML:

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 4: parser error : error parsing attribute name  in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\local.pruebas.com\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 510......

then, its time to debug
1.first: go to app/etc/Ajzele_SimpleModel and force and error, for example:

```
<config>
     <modules>
        <Ajzele_SimpleModel <!--remove a '>' to force an error-->
           <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ajzele_SimpleModel>
     </modules>
</config>
```

you should see the error.

2.second: go to app/code/local/Ajzele/SimpleModel/etc/config.xml and retry the process

```
<config>
    <modules>
      <Ajzele_SimpleModel <!-- remove a '>' to verify that you load correctly your extension 
          <version>0.0.1</version>
      </Ajzele_SimpleModel>
    </modules>
    <global>

      <models>
          <simplemodel>
               <class>Ajzele_SimpleModel_Model</class>
                  <resourceModel>simplemodel_mysql4</resourceModel>      
          </simplemodel>
      </models>
     </global>
 </config>
```

if you don´t have simple xml error in this point you don´t load correctly your extension, and the next step is debug and debug config.xml

This isn´t a concrete answere, but i think that you can see whith the solution with this.
thanks,sorry for my inglish

Comment: Tried ur debugging method, but it just says that it cannot find my installer script when my script is right in the sql/simplemodel_setup folder. Any ideas as to why it cannot find my installer script?

Answer (score 1):

can you try to define in this way:

```
<resources>
        <selo_modulo1_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Selo_Modulo1</module>
            </setup>
        </selo_modulo1_setup>
    </resources>
```

And later put in yourmodule/sql/selo_modulo1_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php, and a example of install script :

```
<?php
die('All right');

/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
/**
 * Create table 'poll'
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('selo_modulo1/blog_post'))
    ->addColumn('post_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Post Id')
    ->addColumn('title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        ), 'Post title')
    ->addColumn('content', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 1024, array(
        ), 'Post content')
    ->setComment('Blog_post');//Comentario de la tabla.
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

And for don´t commit errors my protocol to made extension is copy/paste the code os a similar module of the core and tuning for my use.

Regards david

Comment: So just change the resource part and installer script with your code? But wouldn't <entities></entities> require a change as well since the table name you have mentioned is different than mine?

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple module with your structure, and the setup resource script ran correctly.  You can see that module [here](http://alanstorm.com/2012/projects/Ajzele_SimpleModel.tar.gz).  Diff vs. your module, and once you get an exception being thrown in the installer script, start debugging your SQL line by line.

Comment: I did try debugging my SQL line by line and also ran the sql query in MySQL query window which ran perfectly fine. I think its just that its unable to find my installer script for some reason which happens every time I first run my module. Are there any particular steps I am missing out before creating a new table?

Comment: I followed your article http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources and every thing went fine until the step where you check whether or not the upgrade script ran fine or not. I never get the message 'Running upgrade for.....'

Comment: Also if I then manually delete the row from core_resource table and then add the actual 'CREATE table' script and reload the page, I keep getting the error page. Until I go and manually add the row back. But then my table doesn't get showed up either

Comment: So what could be the possible reason, that every thing happens fine but it never runs my installer script? Or even if it does since I see my module entry in the table, the actual 'CREATE table' SQL never gets executed?

Comment: Any input from your side will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're running in developer mode so that Magento will halt on any exception thrown.  Beyond that it sounds like you're considering too many factors at once.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Place a `die(__FILE__);` statement at the top of your install script, drop the row for your module from core_resources, rm -rf var/cache/mage--* then visit your site in a browser, you should get the filename of your file. If you do remove the die statement and you should be good to go.

My guess is that Magento ran an upgrade when your file didn't contain the code to create the table. Once the version is incremented in core_resources the install script will not re-run.

Comment: I tried placing your die(__FILE__); and deleted the row from the module but I just get an error page, the report of which says it cannot find my my simplemodel_setup.

Comment: Does your setup class definately have the class name of Ajzele_SimpleModel_Model_Mysql4_Setup and is located in app/code/local/Ajzele/SimpleModel/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php?

Comment: Yes it has the right class name and at the right location. I was wondering to start the creation of a module n thereby the table all over again step by step with a different module name. Just to be sure I am not missing out on anything. and would teh Setup.php be mandatory to create then?

Comment: Yes, from what I remember it is mandatory, though I think in newer versions it's be renamespaced to Model/Resource/Setup.php. Since you should be inheriting the Core Setup class, you will need to check on your version of Magento whether it is located in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php or app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php

Comment: Acc to my Magento version (1.6.1) its supposed to b in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php. Also apart from this I just tried creating a separate module from scratch with a different name. I only created the folder structure with absolutely no files in it and just created app/etc/modules/Companyname_Module.xml, cleared my cache n refreshed teh browser, but can't see it in System>>Configuration>>Advanced. This seems strange, any ideas?

Comment: How are you clearing the cache? During development I'd recommend deleting the contents of the cache folder, rather than doing anything through the admin panel. It's also generally a good idea to log out and back in when expecting things to appear / disappear from the admin panel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6477/discussion-between-ivn-and-cags)